# Why can't I customize the application of a struct-id construction function?

Tags: macros, racket, expansion

I would like to build a custom language in Racket that requires redefining the implicit form `#%app`. However, using the macro stepper I noticed that unlike regular "`proc-id`" function application, struct-id application does not get replaced with the custom `#%app` form. Why is this the case?

Comment: This is really unclear. Can you clarify your question? Give us some code example that demonstrates the problem at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that what you are seeing in the macro stepper is a result of the fact that (unless you specify otherwise with keyword options) `struct` binds the struct name to a macro to communicate static information about the struct type, which is used by `match`, `shared`, `struct-out`, and other macros. When used as an expression, this macro expands to the constructor function, which is bound to an otherwise-inaccessible name. If that doesn't seem to explain what you're seeing, perhaps you could give a code example.

In any case, if you disable macro hiding, you will see that direct application of the constructor function does use the correct `#%app` form. For example, this program:

```lisp
#lang racket

(module language racket
  (provide (rename-out [my-app #%app])
           (except-out (all-from-out racket)
                       #%app))
  (define-syntax-rule (my-app rator rand ...)
    (let ()
      (print-app-form '(rator rand ...))
      (rator rand ...)))
  (define (print-app-form quoted)
    (printf "; ~a\n" quoted)))

(module main (submod ".." language)
  (struct bag (contents)
    #:transparent)
  (define groceries
    '(oranges milk salsa))
  (bag groceries))
```

prints the following output, where `bag1` is an artifact of `#%app` being expanded after the `bag` macro:

```
; (bag1 groceries)
(bag '(oranges milk salsa))
```